# QQmlApplicationEngine losing context after it set

Tags: python, qml, pyside2

The code below work correct and I can get `my_model` property in QML file.

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    context = engine.rootContext()
    context.setContextProperty('my_model', MyModel())
    engine.load('path/to/main.qml')
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But `my_model` is null in QML file when I tried to move `setContextProperty` to another function. For example:

```py
def boot_model(context):
    context.setContextProperty('my_model', MyModel())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    context = engine.rootContext()
    boot_model(context)
    engine.load('path/to/main.qml')
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In this case `my_model` will be null in my QML file:

```
ApplicationWindow {
  id: root
  Button {
    onClicked: {
      console.log(my_model) // Output: qml: null
    }
  }
}
```

I found this issue when I tried to create QOject factory.

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Explanation:

The problem is that `MyModel()` is a local variable that will be deleted when the boot_model function is finished executing. From my experience I would expect 2 behaviors depending on the use of PyQt5 or PySide2, in the first case I would expect that it indicates a null as you indicate it, and in the second case I would expect a *Segmentation fault (core dumped)*.

#### Solution:

The solution is to extend the scope of the object of the `MyModel()` class and for this there are several solutions:

- Pass a parent to MyModel:

```py
def boot_model(context):
    model = MyModel()
    model.setParent(context)
    context.setContextProperty("my_model", model)
```

- Make the model an attribute of the context:

```py
def boot_model(context):
    model = MyModel()
    context.model = model
    context.setContextProperty("my_model", model)
```

Comment: I had thoughts about it, but there was no idea how to did it. Anyway this solution works. Thanks you